# beautifulsoup library not showing below #document data inside iframe tag in python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, screen-scraping

url :-> `https://www.greenblottmetal.com/scrap-metal-prices`

problem is :->
---> #document(another url) --->  new

After inspect data available into  tag and inside iframe there is #document is there this is subtype of iframe and holding URL inside "()" and holding ........ I want to scrape data from the table but I'm not able to read from Beautifsoup library object data from this URL and its HTML content. For more visit URL: `https://www.greenblottmetal.com/crap-metal-prices`

Data showing on webpage after inspect:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <iframe class="nKphmK" title="Table Master" aria-label="Table Master" scrolling="no" src="https://wix-visual-data.appspot.com/index?pageId=ee1kv&amp;compId=comp-iokfptn7&amp;viewerCompId=comp-iokfptn7&amp;siteRevision=148&amp;viewMode=site&amp;deviceType=desktop&amp;locale=en&amp;regionalLanguage=en&amp;width=569&amp;height=2957&amp;instance=J_m2kTqVpMO94dlz4vhUuD232Kbag0irUNTSTGpGJmM.eyJpbnN0YW5jZUlkIjoiNDJjNzg3YWYtOTgwYi00MWNlLThmMGQtMjgxMzhmMDVkOTY5IiwiYXBwRGVmSWQiOiIxMzQxMzlmMy1mMmEwLTJjMmMtNjkzYy1lZDIyMTY1Y2ZkODQiLCJtZXRhU2l0ZUlkIjoiZTBmNDk5MWQtN2MxNS00ODU5LWIyYjktMzllZThhMDljZWRjIiwic2lnbkRhdGUiOiIyMDI0LTAzLTI4VDA3OjQxOjU4LjY5N1oiLCJkZW1vTW9kZSI6ZmFsc2UsImFpZCI6IjdmNGVhMTVkLTcxMzctNGZjOC05YzAwLWUwMmNmNDE3YTAwOSIsImJpVG9rZW4iOiJhMjMzMWViMi1lNDFlLTA5OTctM2RiNC0xMWZkMDUwYzE3YjUiLCJzaXRlT3duZXJJZCI6ImI0NmJjNTExLTVlMzYtNDQ3NS05NjEzLWFhNzhmZGVkYzRiZSJ9&amp;commonConfig=%7B%22brand%22%3A%22wix%22%2C%22host%22%3A%22VIEWER%22%2C%22bsi%22%3A%2221aec005-387a-4cdb-bc29-79c09bd8fb5a%7C1%22%2C%22BSI%22%3A%2221aec005-387a-4cdb-bc29-79c09bd8fb5a%7C1%22%7D&amp;currentRoute=.%2Fscrap-metal-prices&amp;vsi=236d7927-567f-4b22-bd97-6cea740fe681" allowfullscreen="" allowtransparency="true" allowvr="true" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay;camera;microphone;geolocation;vr">
        #document (https://wix-visual-data.appspot.com/index?pageId=ee1kv&compId=comp-iokfptn7&viewerCompId=comp-iokfptn7&siteRevision=148&viewMode=site&deviceType=desktop&locale=en&regionalLanguage=en&width=569&height=2957&instance=J_m2kTqVpMO94dlz4vhUuD232Kbag0irUNTSTGpGJmM.eyJpbnN0YW5jZUlkIjoiNDJjNzg3YWYtOTgwYi00MWNlLThmMGQtMjgxMzhmMDVkOTY5IiwiYXBwRGVmSWQiOiIxMzQxMzlmMy1mMmEwLTJjMmMtNjkzYy1lZDIyMTY1Y2ZkODQiLCJtZXRhU2l0ZUlkIjoiZTBmNDk5MWQtN2MxNS00ODU5LWIyYjktMzllZThhMDljZWRjIiwic2lnbkRhdGUiOiIyMDI0LTAzLTI4VDA3OjQxOjU4LjY5N1oiLCJkZW1vTW9kZSI6ZmFsc2UsImFpZCI6IjdmNGVhMTVkLTcxMzctNGZjOC05YzAwLWUwMmNmNDE3YTAwOSIsImJpVG9rZW4iOiJhMjMzMWViMi1lNDFlLTA5OTctM2RiNC0xMWZkMDUwYzE3YjUiLCJzaXRlT3duZXJJZCI6ImI0NmJjNTExLTVlMzYtNDQ3NS05NjEzLWFhNzhmZGVkYzRiZSJ9&commonConfig=%7B%22brand%22:%22wix%22,%22host%22:%22VIEWER%22,%22bsi%22:%2221aec005-387a-4cdb-bc29-79c09bd8fb5a%7C1%22,%22BSI%22:%2221aec005-387a-4cdb-bc29-79c09bd8fb5a%7C1%22%7D&currentRoute=.%2Fscrap-metal-prices&vsi=236d7927-567f-4b22-bd97-6cea740fe681)
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body class="js-focus-visible">
                <div id="appContainer">
                    <section class="main-content ng-scope" ng-if="!main.hasError" ng-class="{'show-sortable': main.settings.tableParams.sortable}">
                        <div footable="" class="direction-right" style="height: 100%; width:100%; display: block" data-settings="main.settings" data-instance-id="main.instanceId" data-comp-id="main.compId" data-fixed-height="main.isFixedHeight()" data-filter-position="main.getFilterPosition()"><!-- ngIf: fixedHeight -->
                    <!-- ngIf: !fixedHeight --><div class="adjust-height-view ng-scope" adjust-height-view="" ng-if="!fixedHeight"><section style="width:100%;" ng-show="settings.tableParams.showHeaderFooter &amp;&amp; !isEmptyTable" class="ng-hide">
                        <table id="filterTable" class="filter outerBorder" style="width:100%;" ng-class="{'mobile':isMobile}">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="100%">
                            <div id="filterBox" ng-show="settings.tableParams.filter" class="ng-hide"></div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        </table>
                    </section>
                    <div id="tableWrapper" style="min-height: 2757px; height: 100%;">
                        <table id="theTable" style="width: 100%; display: table; height: 100%;" dir="auto" data-paging="false" data-cascade="true" data-filter-min="3" data-paging-size="5" data-useparentwidth="true" data-filter-container="#filterBox" data-filter-connectors="false" data-use-parent-width="false" data-sorting="" data-filtering="" data-filter-filters="[]" data-filter-placeholder="Search" data-filter-position="right" data-show-header="true" ng-class="{'empty-table':isEmptyTable}" class="footable table outerBorder footable-1 breakpoint-x-small"><thead><tr class="footable-header"><th class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">COPPER &amp; BRASS</th><th class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;"></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">#1 Bare Bright Wire&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$3.10/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">#1 Copper Tubing / Flashing&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$3.00/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">#2 Copper Tubing / Bus Bar&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$2.75/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">#3 Roofing Copper&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$2.40/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Brass (Plumbing, Pipe)&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$2.15/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Red Brass or Bronze&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$2.25/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Brass Shells&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$2.15/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Brass Water Meter&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$2.15/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Clean Brass Auto Radiators&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$2.00/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Aluminum/Copper Coil (Clean)&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$1.48/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Aluminum/Copper Coil (Dirty)&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$.85/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">COPPER BEARING MATERIAL&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Copper Transformers&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.30/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Electric Motors&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.30/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Alternators/Starters&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.22/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Sealed Units/Compressors&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.25/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">INSULATED COPPER WIRE&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Insulated Copper Wire (Cat 5/6)&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.85/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">THHN Cable&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$1.55/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">500-750 MCM (Bare Bright Inside)&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$1.70/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Hollow Heliax Wire&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$1.10/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Romex Wire&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$1.35/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Insulated Cable&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.55/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Steel BX&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.45/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Aluminum BX&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.90/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">low grade insulated wire 30% &nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.45/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">ALUMINUM&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Aluminum Siding&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.47/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Sheet Aluminum&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.47/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Aluminum Rims&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.74/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Aluminum Truck Rims&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.47/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Aluminum Chrome Rims&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.47/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Aluminum Windows frames&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.47/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Cast Aluminum&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.42/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Bare Aluminum Wire&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.57/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">AL Thermo-pane/break (Not Glass)&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.47/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">AL Litho Plates&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.60/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">AL Machine Cuts&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.60/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Aluminum Transformers&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.06/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">AL Turnings&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.18/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Unprepared aluminum&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">                          $0.40/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Irony aluminum&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">                          $0.11/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">MISCELLANEOUS SCRAP&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Car Batteries&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.17/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Steel Case Battery (forklift)&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.12/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Lead&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.50/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">304 Stainless Steel (Non-Magnetic)&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.35/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">316 Stainless Steel (Non-Magnetic)&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.65/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Lead Wheel Weights&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.10/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Ballasts&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.06/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Scrap Generators&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.06/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Catalyic Converter&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Prices Vary&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">STEEL &amp; IRON&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Short Steel&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$225/G.t. ($0.10/lb)&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Light Iron &amp; Tin &amp; appliances&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$ 160/G.t. ($0.07/lb)&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Cast Iron&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$ 225/G.t. ($0.10/lb)&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Plate &amp; Structural&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$ 235/G.t. ($0.10/lb)&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Unprepared steel torching&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">       $ 160/G.t. ($0.07/lb)&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Unprepared steel shearing&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">       $ 215/g.t. ($.095/lb)&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">COMPUTER SCRAP&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Motherboards&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$.60/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Power Supplies (w/Wires)&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.05/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Harddrive PC Board&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.10/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Telecom Equipment&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.07-$0.25/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Servers&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.07-$0.25/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">RARE EARTH METALS&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Carbide Inserts/Shapes&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$2.00-$8.50/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Monel&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$2.00-$2.80/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Titanium&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.40/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Nickel&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$3.00 and up&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Inconel&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$ 2.50/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">Tin Solder&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">$0.40-$3.00/lb&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableOdd"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="footableEven"><td class="wixColumns footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">PRICES SUBJECT TO CHANGE WITHOUT NOTICE ...&nbsp;</td><td class="wixColumns footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
                    </div>
                    <section style="width:100%;margin:0;">
                        <table id="pagerFilter" class="footable footer outerBorder ng-hide" style="width: 100%; margin: 0px;" ng-show="settings.tableParams.showHeaderFooter">
                        <tfoot id="noPager">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="100%" style="height:26px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </section>
                    </div><!-- end ngIf: !fixedHeight -->
                    </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using beautifsoup library in python but  tag holds only below data for iframe is

```
<iframe class="nKphmK" title="Table Master" aria-label="Table Master" scrolling="no" src="./Scrap Metal Prices _ Greenblott Metal Co. _ Binghamton, NY_files/index.html" allowfullscreen="" allowtransparency="true" allowvr="true" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay;camera;microphone;geolocation;vr">
</iframe>
```

for data for either for #document nor for table inside #document.